# Using absolute path for files outside public_html

Tags: php, html

I already did a lot of research on including files outside of public_html but none have been working, so that is why I am posting.

My file structure is like this:

```
>home
   >username
      >includes
         resources.php
      >public_html
         index.php
```

On index.php, I want to include resources.php so I have this:

```
include_once("/home/username/includes/resources.php");
```

However it does not work. If I change it to this for example (and also put another 'resources.php' in public_html) then it does

```
include_once("/home/username/public_html/resources.php");
```

Why doesn't the absolute path using 'includes' work? How can I use an absolute path for files outside of public_html?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this would be considered a duplicate (I couldn't find anything specific like this).

Comment: Why not use a relative path? `../includes/resources.php`

Comment: I'd like to include resources.php on multiple pages on different directory levels, and if i'd move files between directories i would have to re-do the relative paths every time. That's why I'd prefer absolute paths.

Comment: If that's the case, you might want to set a base path for your includes ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)) so that you can just do `include_once("/resources.php")` from any directory

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. But I tried using the relative path like you first suggested but that still didn't work. Is something wrong with my server's configuration?

Comment: Include the error message in the question. If you don't see one, change `include_once` to `require_once`.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, PHP is usually restricted inside public_html, and has no access outside of that path.

Generally speaking, you should put all directories that you need access from PHP inside public_html, and also use relative paths.

Comment: I put those php files outside of public_html because they need to be secure. Is there a way to keep them above public_html and still include them within files in public_html?

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the account the webserver & php runs as has no access to your home directory, so /home/username/includes/resources.php won't work.

You can check this with ls -l /home/username You'll probably see that the web server doesn't have any permissions to "includes".

If you check /home/username/public_html, I'll bet you find that the permissions **do** allow access by the web server, which is why it does work.